# Using char* to store data and error produced

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, char

```
const char* val1 = advertisedDevice.getAddress().toString().c_str();
Serial.printf("Advertised Device: %s \n", val1);
```

This code is used to retrieve the MAC address of a BLE device.
The output of `val1` on the serial monitor is:

> Advertised Device: 45:89:a2:d8:74:65

But when I try to output `val1` individually the system crashes. The code is shown below. Why is this?

```
Serial.printf("Val is : %s", val1[0]);
```

I should expect the serial monitor is print out

> Val is : 4

I am also trying to store `val1` is a string array, so for example

pseudo-code

```
String arr[50];
loop{
    const char* val1 = advertisedDevice.getAddress().toString().c_str();
    Serial.printf("Advertised Device: %s \n", val1);

    arr[i] = val1[0]+val1[1]+val1[2]+....+val1[18]
    i++;
}
```

I want to store it in a single array because I then upload it to a database. I cant do this if its in the form of *val1[0],val1[1]...* and so on. It will be easier to store all the data in a single array location i.e.

```
arr[1] = "45:47:89:fd:12", 
arr[2] = "47:AC:1b:24:58" and so on.
```

Is this right?

Comment: What’s the point of that last line adding them all together?  Why do you feel you need fifty String objects for that?

Comment: @Delta_G I want to store it in a single array because I then upload it to a database. I cant do this if its in the form of val1[0],val1[1]... and so on. It will be easier to store all the data in a single array location i.e. arr[1] = "45:47:89:fd:12", arr[2] = "47:AC:1b:24:58" and so on. There are also 50 MAC addresses I want to store

Answer (score 0):

```
Serial.printf("Val is : %s", val1[0]);
```

`%s` expects a string of characters, i.e. a `char *` or `const char *` variable. `val1` is a `const char *`, so `val1[0]` is a `char` that is the first character within `val1`. You need to change `%s` to `%c`, or else Serial.printf will believe the value of `val1[0]` is an address to a string of characters, causing a crash or undefined behavior.

If you meant for `val1` to be an array of strings, you need to declare it as that. For example:

```
const char *val1[50];
val1[0] = advertisedDevice.getAddress().toString().c_str();
Serial.printf("Val is : %s", val1[0]); // Now this will work
```

---

**Edit:** If you're looking to build a list of strings out of `arr`, you should be able to simply assign to `arr` and access the strings through it:

```
String arr[50];
loop{
    arr[i] = advertisedDevice.getAddress().toString().c_str();
    // If above doesn't work, try: arr[i] = String(...);
    Serial.printf("Advertised Device: %s \n", arr[i]);

    i++;
}
```

Comment: Your explanation is correct but your fix isn’t. There’s no need to make `val1` an array of strings, and either way it still accesses invalid memory after the object lifetime has ended.